# Unset search after leaving page

Tags: search

In my drupal admin content page when I search for something it keeps displaying the searched items.

Even when I leave the page and go back it is still displaying items from the search querie

When I press the Clear button the results are normal again. How can I fix this when I leave the content page that it automatically clears the search results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on line 41 in the find_content.module the default value gets filled in.. you could comment this out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) you can edit the view and change the exposed filters and uncheck "remember the last selection".

A screenshot to illustrate this for the content:title field:

[image: Exposed filter - remember the last selection check]

Comment: Thanks. But I'm afraid that doesn't work with the Find Content module?

Comment: on line 41 in the find_content.module the default value gets filled in.. you could comment this out.